# Can someone identify this vine for me which seems to be wrapping tightly around many trees?

Tags: trees, tree-care, vines, urban-gardening

[image][image][image]There are many similar to this vine in a city park in NYC.  They seem to be wrapping themselves tightly around many trees.

Comment: leaves, we need to see the leaves...

Answer (score 2):

It is not a certainty (there are other woody vines that look similar), but visually it looks a lot like a Wisteria vine.  It is a very aggressive vine and needs to be pruned often or they will grow out of control. I have one that is doing the same thing as in your photo. A long horizontal "runner" comes out from the base (of original plant) and spreads to neighboring trees where it roots and finds support. They then grow up very high into the canopy. Here are two links that describes Wisteria. Hope this helps.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisteria

http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=867